# Signing In to AWS console using AWS SDK iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services

I'm currently exploring AWS SNS, to integrate AWS SNS using AWS iOS SDK.

The guide shows that we have to use Amazon Cognito for authentication and then we can register the device token in the application created in AWS SNS.

Guide that I'm following - https://medium.com/aws-activate-startup-blog/a-guide-to-amazon-simple-notification-service-mobile-push-self-registration-for-ios-a2502e8d5fbd#.mt7t7ed89

After integrating this in my project - I get this error:

```
Error 
Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSSNSErrorDomain 
Code=1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.amazonaws.AWSSNSErrorDomain error 1.)" 
UserInfo=0x12847e0 
{   
    Type=Sender, 
    Message=User: arn:aws:sts::xxxxxxxxx:assumed-role/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: SNS:CreatePlatformEndpoint on resource: arn:aws:sns:ap-south-1:xxxxxxxxx:app/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, 
    __text=(
    "\n    ",
    "\n    ",
    "\n    ",
    "\n  "
    ),
Code=AuthorizationError}
```

So please help me out to proceed.

Let me know steps to integrate AWS APIs for Authentication Flow in iOS.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you Generate `AWS` ACCESS_KEY & SECRET_KEY and initialize `AmazonSNSClient`  ? also we need to set `ENDPOINT` from our application  have you set that `endPoint` ?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, EndPoint was set when I accessed the API. (there was mismatch in the region so I was not able to create EndPoint)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry that you're having trouble with this.
Do check if you have added SNS:CreatePlatformEndpoint to the policy for both Auth and Unauth roles on the specified resource.

It should look something like...

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sns:CreatePlatformEndpoint"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:sns:ap-south-1:xxxxxxxxx:app/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I had not mentioned the actual region in AWSServiceConfiguration so, I was not able to create endPoint now its fine.